# How to update an entity in DB effectively?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to update an entity in the database whenever the entity in my application contains data that is different from the DB entity.

My update method is as follows:

```
    @Transactional
    public void updateEntity(String a, String b, boolean c, Date d) { //some more params
        MyEntity entity = dao.findEntityBy(a, b, c); //might be some more params
        //nullcheck

        if (!entity.getA().equals(a)) {
            entity.setA(a);
        }
        if (!entity.getB().equals(b)) {
            entity.setB(b);
        }
        //repeat per property... a-n

        dao.save(entity);
    }
```

Question: 
Should I check each attribute of the entity if it has changed and then only use the setter? Or should I just skip the checks and just override the entity?

```
MyEntity entity = dao.findEntityBy(a, b, c);
entity.setA(a);
entity.setB(b);
//...
dao.save(entity);
```

What is the perfered way? What are (dis)advantages of either solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much in every "production ready" software you can see second version

```
MyEntity entity = dao.findEntityBy(a, b, c);
entity.setA(a);
entity.setB(b);
//...
dao.save(entity);
```

To be honest I don't see added value in first option (but added maintenance and lower readability can be seen).

Answer (score 3):

In case you have many attributes, you can use the `dynamic-update=true` to optimize the performance. The dynamic-update attribute tells Hibernate whether to include unmodified properties in the SQL UPDATE statement.

It can be configured as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_ENTITY")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        dynamicUpdate = true
)
public class MyEntity {
}
```

Comment: Do I also have to set `selectBeforeUpdate = true`? Or would this trigger an additional select and is not needed because I already selected the entity within `@Transactional`?

Comment: And would you consider the benefit of the `@DynamicUpdate` is that big that the fact that hibernate has to regenerate every sql statement dynamically can be neglected? We're talking about entity records with a string.length of approx 200 chars, where often eg only a single number of a row is to be updated (eg stock availability).

Comment: About selectBeforeUpdate = true, i don't think you should use it but it would be good to see what happens practically if you specify it. About dynamic-update, the column numbers is what matters not the column value.

Comment: Ok, it's about 15 cols, what do you think concerning this?